# matlab showing 0 for small number values product

Tags: matlab, matrix, product

I have matrix with elements have small values. I am taking product of some elements of matrix for 100 times. If I take matrix 10*10 then it shows output but when I take matrix 100*100 then it shows 0. I think it shows 0 because product appears very small value. so how to take product so this small value should display.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing:

```
format long
```

It should be just and rounding problem. This will format it to 8 decimals. If you want to go back to Matlab default settings type:

```
format short
```

Comment: 10*10 matrix product value shows 1.42185374673164e-108. format long g also not works i.e. output shows 0.

Comment: matlab showing approximately upto 2.835313878787100e-314 but not below this.

Comment: Yeah they do show up to that value, but at some iteration it probably goes below 'eps' that is lowest value it can work with. Since when I try generating random matrix 100x100 and using 'prod(M)' it works fine so your values are probably too small.